# Spring boot doesn't run on heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku

My question is about: When I deploy my project on heroku, my api doesn't run and I can not find the reason. I will put here the logs of my aplication and my github repository

I have already tried changing my springboot.run class, but it doesn't work.

[The application deploy normaly, but the spring wont run.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tMTL.png)

Github of my aplication: https://github.com/marcusvlc/labspring

Comment: Do you get an error? What is the output of `heroku logs`? Have you run `heroku ps:scale web=1`?

Comment: The heroku log image is in this post. I'm not getting any errors, the spring server does not even roll.

Comment: Try `Heroku ps:scale web=1`